# Why would a tableadaptor stop execution of code block?

Tags: winforms, tableadapter

```
    private void form_Load()
    {
        this.purchase_OrderTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Purchase_Order);
        this.purchase_Order_ItemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Purchase_Order_Items);
        this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.purchase_Order_DataSet.Inventory);

        part_NumberComboBox.SelectedValue = 0;
        order_QuantityTextBox.Text = "";
        part_DescriptionTextBox.Text = "";
        vendorTextBox.Text = "";

        part_NumberComboBox.Select();
    }
```

I have rebuilt this form twice to get it working properly.  Now it doesn't work properly again.  Code execution exits the code block when executing the `inventoryTableAdapter` and I can't figure out why.  Any idea's?

Comment: Some forms of exception maybe, wrap up code with a try catch block, then set a debugging breakpoint in the catch block and inspect the exception object.

Comment: @TamimSalem; I put the code in a `try catch` and it worked fine.  I took away the `try catch` and it still worked fine.  It must be the code gremlins.  I will leave it in the `try catch` incase it happens again.

Comment: I would like to remove this post because the code actually works perfectly.  I had found something completely off from this code block that was causing my problem.  I am also trying to fix my other posts in an effort to be allowed to ask questions again.          let me know if anyone has any reason that I shouldn't delete this post.